# Setting output name to be same as input name in ModelBuilder using Parse Path?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, esri-ascii-raster, file-path

Can you comment on my model as to why the output name is totally different from input name?

[image]

Comment: Obvious question what are the names?

Comment: name is 3b42rt.2013120100

Comment: Your input name contains a period which ModelBuilder assumes the preceding text is a file extension (so Arc assigns a default output name).

Comment: after i removed the period. the output name is still remain default. why?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format. Please start using the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.